# Ruby Proc object as public member variable doesn't work?

Tags: ruby

I am a bit of a Ruby noob when it comes to the more advanced features. Currently I am experiencing with Proc objects. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code sample?

```
class Tester
  @printer = Proc.new do |text|
    puts text
  end
  attr_accessor :printer
end

t = Tester.new
t.printer.call("Hello!")
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Test.rb:10: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I don't immediately see why it shouldn't work. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting `@printer` in the class's `initialize` method. This'll work:

```
class Tester
  def initialize
    @printer = Proc.new { |t| puts t }
  end
  attr_accessor :printer
end
```

Comment: Further info: The @printer variable defined in StackedCrooked's code belongs to the Tester class itself. Outside of instance methods, all code in a class definition uses the class as `self` — so if you set an instance variable, you're setting an instance variable of the class (which is an instance of Class) rather than an instance variable of any particular instance.